# Kerberos authentication enabled web application generating non Kerberos token in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, kerberos, windows-authentication, iis-10

We have enabled Kerberos authentication in two different servers under the IIS settings. But the Kerberos token which is generated in one of the servers always starting with "TlR". We have added NTLM and Negotiate providers under Windows Authentication. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

**Development Server:**

```
Request Headers: Authorization Negotiate oXcwdaADCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Response Headers: WWW-Authenticate Negotiate oRswGaADCxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**QA Server:**

```
Request Headers: Authorization Negotiate TlRMxxxxxxxxxxx
Response Headers: WWW-Authenticate NTLM,Negotiate
```

Comment: Do both servers have the same Kerberos authentication setup and configuration?

Comment: @YurongDai, Yes, we have verified the configuration in both of the servers. There is no difference between them. We are trying to call another API application inside the same server from web application via HttpClient by passing the Kerberos token. But the API application keeps on rejecting the call. We are getting 401.1 error.

Comment: Check the Windows event log on the server for any Kerberos-related errors or warnings. These logs may provide more details about authentication failures.

Answer (score 2):

Do you activate the kerberos on the client browsers?

Firefox `about/config` and find `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` key, insert or comma-separate append `mydomain.com` so that Firefox initiates a kerberos sso auth.

IE browser used to have an option `Tools/Internet Options/Security/Local Intranet/Sites/Advanced` and Chrome was using the same registry values. I have not tested on Edge browser.

```
Login request hedaer token prefix:
Negotiate TlR* = SPNEGO over NTLM (may not be the one you want)
Negotiate YII* = SPNEGO over Kerberos (this is what you expect to see?)
```

Also you need to use a separate machine for client, most likely `kerberos YII*` token not working on the same server+client machine.

Comment: I didn't activate the Kerberos on the client browser. In Dev server, the token starts with oXc. In QA server, the token starts with TlR. How it will differ if I use the same browser?